# Codeigniter - Querying 2 times in controller then passing the values in the view

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, view, model, controller

The first array that had been passed, its values can be outputted while the second array produces an error.. we tried to use print_r command on both array and it contains a value

Here's what we tried

controller

```
$project['project'] = (call model with return value);
$amenity['amenity'] = (call model with return value);

$data['project'] = $project;
$data['amenity'] = $amenity;

$this->load->view('view.php', $data);
```

view

```
//this code works
foreach($project is $i){
     echo 'title: '.$i[0]->title;
}
//this code produce error, undefined object $amenity
foreach($amenity is $j){
     echo 'amenity: '.$j[0]->amenity;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
$data['project'] = (call model with return value);
$data['amenity'] = (call model with return value);

$this->load->view('view.php', $data);
```

View:

```
// foreach for $project
foreach($project as $i){
     echo 'title: '.$i['title'];
}
// foreach for $amenity
foreach($amenity as $j){
     echo 'amenity: '.$j['amenity'];
}
```

Comment: thank you but there's a new error that showed up. "cannot use object of type std:Class as arrays in ... "

Comment: @Katherine Check again please, because I did one update, I change `is` into `as` in `foreach`

Comment: If you have the same problem, please Update the quesiton and tell me the model how did you do?

Comment: I see, i typed it wrong here, but I used "as" in my real code

Comment: didn't work yet.. when i run the print_r($amenity), the values that it shows are the values that print_r($project). we have a problem in model i think

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34573/discussion-between-erman-belegu-and-katherine)